# Kubernetes liveness probes stop responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes

I'm using `kube-aws` to set up a production Kubernetes cluster on AWS. Now I'm running into an issue I am unable to recreate in my dev environment.

When a pod is running heavy computation, which in my case happens in bursts, the liveness and readiness probes stop responding. In my local environment, where I run docker compose, they work as expected.

The probes use simple HTTP 204 No Content output using native Go functionality.

Has anyone seen this before?

**EDIT:**
I'd be happy to provide more information, but I am uncertain what I should provide as there is a tremendous amount of configuration and code involved. Primarily, I'm looking for help to troubleshoot and where to look to try to locate the actual issue.

Comment: You have to supply the code for us to possibly diagnose issues with the code. You are likely constrained by some resource[s] (CPU, IO, FDs etc.), but there's no data here to begin to guess.

Comment: Can you also clarify what you mean by 'in my local env, where I run Docker compose'? Do you mean your dev and prod environment are totally different?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @JimB, what code are you looking for? The Goland is simply the `net/http` package writing a header. Kubernetes-wise, what configuration are you looking for?

@MichaelHausenblas My system consists of microservices written in Golang, built into Docker containers. Locally, I orchestrate them with Docker Compose, in production, I use Kubernetes to run them. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @HelgeTalvikSöderström: you have a StackOverflow question tagged as Go, so I assume this has to do with Go code. If the responses aren't coming from a Go program you are building, there's not much here we can do. If the responses are coming from a Go program, it's not likely the simple http endpoint that's at fault, but the system interaction as a whole. You need to start debugging by breaking the system down into discrete parts, to figure out what might be causing the responses to hang.

Comment: It might be helpful to describe the concurrency model the app uses- are HTTP requests dispatched to go routines or are they handled inline? Are liveness and readiness handled similarly to other requests, or is there a separate listener and service loop for them? And when you look at CPU and RAM utilization of your pods under load- are they hitting limits or is there capacity?

Comment: Thanks Jonah, good input! It seems I am hitting limits, so I have increased them. Most likely, this was the issue. Regarding the go code, the liveness and readiness probes are handled inline through a regular `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))` with a `GET`-handler function simply running `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)`.

Comment: If adding resources will not help, I'll start from investigation of "does probes are able to reach server code?"